# Java ant build jsonix

Tags: java, ant, jsonix

how do i build the following using ant?

http://sourceforge.net/p/jsonix/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/samples/

```
bash-3.2$ ant -buildfile project-build.xml
Buildfile: /Users/user/Desktop/sandbox/jsonix-code-293-trunk/samples/po/project-build.xml

generate-sources:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/Desktop/sandbox/jsonix-code-293-trunk/samples/po/project-build.xml:9: /Users/user/Desktop/sandbox/jsonix-code-293-trunk/samples/po/lib does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: You could try to create the lib directory manually if this works add `<mkdir dir="${basedir}/lib">` to the ant file.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm just doing something wrong :))

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the lib to the build path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsonix author here.

Jsonix itselfs built with Maven. So you actually have to do something like:

```
mvn clean install
```

This will generate three ZIPs in `target` directory:

- jsonix-samples-po-VERSION-batch-src.zip - sample batch/command line project
- jsonix-samples-po-VERSION-maven-src.zip - sample Maven project
- jsonix-samples-po-VERSION-ant-src.zip - sample Ant project

(Or just get these ZIP from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsonix/files/)).

These ZIPs are distrubutions of sample "Purchase Order" project for Ant, Maven and command line.

Apparently you're interested in Ant sample, so unzip the `jsonix-samples-po-<VERSION>-ant-src.zip` and run `ant`.